# How can I improve the following mySql query to use PDO prepared statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table "my_table" with the following fields

```
object_id: number | object_type: varchar | object_value: text
```

Sample data:

```
4 | post | Lorem ipsum
2 | file | Lorem ipsum
3 | post | Lorem ipsum
2 | page | Lorem ipsum
1 | post | Lorem ipsum
2 | file | Lorem ipsum
```

I have an array of objects containing the object_id and object_types. Is there a better way to do the following query, and if so how would it look in a PDO prepared statement?

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE (object_id = 4 AND object_type = 'post')
OR (object_id = 2 AND object_type = 'file')
OR (object_id = 3 AND object_type = 'post');
```

Thanks to any responders

Answer (score 3):

This will work `(object_id, object_type) IN ((4, 'post'), (2, 'file'), (3, 'post'))`.

If the number of tuples in your `in` list varies, you'll need to dynamically construct the query (and list of parameters) you give to PDO.

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f8ac0/2) is a working sqlfiddle with this syntax.

Comment: Thanks Uueerdo and @FrankerZ, that seems like a much cleaner solution to my query... but is it possible to add that to a PDO prepared statement?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

```
select * from mytable
where (object_id, object_type) in (
    select 4, 'post' union all 
    select 2, 'file' union all 
    select 3, 'post')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b8668/3)

Or

```
select * from mytable
where (object_id, object_type) in ((4, 'post'), (2, 'file'), (3, 'post'))
```

Comment: This seems more cumbersome

Comment: @FirstOne -- good point, I was just trying to show an alternative solution.  `dynamic sql` might be the only approach for that scenario.

Comment: @sgeddes I decided to delete my comment and get the op's confirmation first ;).. and yeah, dynamic query is probably what the op will have to end up doing

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes, I like the example of the second query using IN, but is it possible to add that to a prepared statement?

Comment: @jon -- unfortunately no, not unless you know the number of potential values in the array.  If you know the maximum number of potential values, you could create a prepared statement (just add all the parameters some of which would evaluate to null because they don't exist in the array).  If you don't, then `dynamic sql` is your only option.

Comment: @sgeddes you actually can use prepared statements. For example, in pdo, you create a query with a bunch of `?` as placeholders and pass the values as array in the `execute` method. Take a look at Example #3 on [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). Create the dynamic query with placeholders base on the number of objects and pass the values to the `execute` method.

Comment: @FirstOne -- I've never done that before, thanks for the article, great read.

Comment: @jon -- Look at the comment from FirstOne -- looks like it's easier than I thought with pdo.

Comment: Thanks both, I have used ? before to create a dynamic PDO prepared statement, just not in the format above. I have edited my question to include an example of what I think might work as I can't add it to a comment. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to the guys above for their answers. You have helped me come up with the following dynamic PDO prepared statement.

```
// THIS IS MY ARRAY OF OBJECTS
$data[0]['object_id']=4;
$data[0]['object_type']='post';
$data[1]['object_id']=2;
$data[1]['object_type']='file';

// CREATING A DYNAMIC PDO PREPARED STATEMENT 
$sql="SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (object_id, object_type) IN (";
$i=0;
foreach($data as $datum){
    if($i!=0){
        $sql.=",";
    }
    $i=1;
    $sql.="(?,?)";
}
$sql.=")";

$stmt=$connection->prepare($sql);

$execute_data=array();
foreach($data as $datum){
    array_push($execute_data,$datum['object_id']);
    array_push($execute_data,$datum['object_type']);
}
$stmt->execute($execute_data);
```